# Get all values from web service API without iterating through every item

Tags: c#, rest, web-services

I've build a small C# application that has been able to get all values I wanted, specifically this is about products, from a webservice API. I have just switched to a larger database (via webservice API access) and now finding out that I get blocked while iterating through the requests, since I've gone from 25 products to 1000 products.

Well, honestly I'm guessing this is the case, but the database is the same built in both my trails, so what has changed is just the amount.

Might mention that I'm new to the whole conect of using webservices/API:s.

I have not tried anything specific yet. I guess one could use a timer between the requests, to have the server rest in between.

Currently I'm iterating through the list of all products, getting their URI, then each URI to get the specifics about each product.

In the best of worlds, I would like to either find a solution whichs allows me to make the numer of reqests lesser than what it is today, or to find a way to let the service rest from making requests. I.e. compare to SQL SELECT * FROM dbTable, make one request, use it

Anyone have any good suggestions. Thanks :)

Thanks to Jeremy, I understand that my backgroundinfo was incomplete. My programs purpose is to fetch all the data from a webshop (products) and distribute them to other systems. So this process of iterating through them will happen ever so often, to detect changes made to the products.

Comment: I don't know how you are showing all that info, are users expected to scroll through 1,000 rows? Typically you chunk up the results, eg search, paging, filters. Also you typically don't see detailed record info until you drill down and this is usually an AJAX request.

Comment: You can have pagination. You need to have API returning only few information about the products and only for a few products. The API should support accepting page number as argument so that it will return only that particular page of data.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for putting my attention to the details of my question. As now stated above the purpose is to fetch all product to detect changes made to the products and distribute the changes to other systems. SSH, which was my first approach worked good, as I could query the database direct, but at the live host for one site, they didn't offer that option suggesting a rebuild to use the included web service. Maybe my approach is flaud since I need to fetch all and do it like every five minutes?

Comment: Chetan, thanks for your reply, I'm not sure about the terminology used, but if I understand you right that is what my program does to retrieve the information. First go through all the href to get the URIs of every product, then iterated through all the href to get the specific details about every product.